# Simulink Bus Creator block Input names using command line

Tags: command-line, simulink

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the names of the input signals of a Bus Creator block in Simulink using the get_param function.

thanks,
Ross

Comment: I used the following:

params = get_param('modelName/BusName','ObjectParameters');

using 'ObjectParameters' in this format creates an output with all the block parameters. Then I used 

names = get_param('modelName/BusName','InputSignalNames');

to get the names in a cell array.

Comment: If the code in your comment answers the question, you should post it as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: Thanks Praetorian. It seems I have low reputation to answer this question myself.